# Can't draw .jpeg on a JPanel

Tags: image, jpanel, draw

I'm working on a Game where I need to draw a board and pawns actively when I move them. I've searched for a few hours now, but I can't find a solution.

They're located in the same folder as the classes.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {   
            Image board = new ImageIcon("images/ChackerBoard.jpeg").getImage();
            Image black = new ImageIcon("images\\BlackPawn.jpeg").getImage();
            Image white = new ImageIcon("images\\WhitePawn.jpeg").getImage();

            this.setSize(320, 320);

            g.drawImage(board, 0, 0, this);
            for (int i = 0; i < Game.BlackList.size(); i++) {
                g.drawImage(black, (Game.BlackList.get(i).GetX() * 40) - 36, (Game.BlackList.get(i).GetY() * 40) - 36, this);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Game.WhiteList.size(); i++) {
                g.drawImage(white, (Game.WhiteList.get(i).GetX() * 40) - 36, (Game.WhiteList.get(i).GetY() * 40) - 36, this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhuc2.jpg

http://imageshack.us/a/img7/8673/checkerboardo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

@FailX in paintComponent, imageobserver object is null. Set the image observer as "this" and it works.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent( g );
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this); //Image is also drawn
    g.drawLine( 10, 10, 100, 50 ); //Line is drawn
    g.draw3DRect(20,20,50,30,true); // Rectangle is drawn
}
```